# I want to build a next word predictor, but I want it to go beyond just using n-grams. What are some ways I could do this?

Tags: nlp, nltk, prediction

I have been trying to learn NLTK and NLP, but to use n-grams to build a next word predictor seems to be relatively simple. What are some other ways I might approach this problem?

Answer (score 1):

This is called Language Modeling. It is one of the primary tasks in NLP. [This article](http://karpathy.github.io/2015/05/21/rnn-effectiveness/) is old now, but it explains in detail how to build a character level language model (given chars c_0 through c_(n-1), predict character c_n).

LSTMs are the best balance of resource-usage and accuracy. [ULM-FIT](http://nlp.fast.ai/classification/2018/05/15/introducing-ulmfit.html) is the best example of LSTM language modeling. Most state of the art results are using enormous Transformers, like the famous BERT* and GPT-2.

- BERT isn't a traditional language model - rather than predicting the next word, it gets a sentence with a blank, and fills in the blank; this is now called MLM, Masked Language Modeling.